# Bug when running pygame, only clears screen when minimized

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am building my first larger game (an Action RPG) with pygame, and was just starting when I ran into this bizarre bug. I ran my code, and the title screen appeared, like normal, and then when i clicked, it advances, but the screen does not change. Until, I minimize the window. then the screen moves. it is not frozen, because i stuck some print functions in for debugging (that is also how i know it actually advances)

I wont put all the code, just the possibly problematic parts:

```
def ChoiceScreen():
    '''choose which option the player wants'''
    print('ChoiceScreen called')
    SURFACE.fill(COLOURS['white'])

    LabelPlay = pg.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
    PlaySurf=LabelPlay.render('New Game', True, COLOURS['black'], \
                                               COLOURS['white'])
    PlayRect = PlaySurf.get_rect()
    PlayRect.center = ((WIN_X // 2), (WIN_Y // 2) - 50)
    SURFACE.blit(PlaySurf, PlayRect)

    #################################################################

    LabelLoad = pg.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
    LoadSurf=LabelLoad.render('Load Game', True, COLOURS['black'], \
                                               COLOURS['white'])
    LoadRect = LoadSurf.get_rect()
    LoadRect.center = (WIN_X // 2, WIN_Y // 2)
    SURFACE.blit(LoadSurf, LoadRect)

    #################################################################

    LabelLoadEarlier = pg.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
    LESurf=LabelLoadEarlier.render('Load Earlier Save', True, COLOURS['black'], \
                                                              COLOURS['white'])
    LERect = LESurf.get_rect()
    LERect.center = (WIN_X // 2, WIN_Y // 2 + 50)
    SURFACE.blit(LESurf, LERect)

    while True:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            elif event.type==MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                x, y = event.pos
                if PlayRect.collidepoint(x,y):
                    print("PlayRect Clicked")
                    #more to come
                elif LoadRect.collidepoint(x,y):
                    print("LoadRect Called")
                elif LERect.collidepoint(x,y):
                    print("LERect called")
```

by the way, COLOURS (I am Canadian) is a dictionary with string keys of RGB tuples, WIN_X is 800, WIN_Y is 600

The IDE i am using is Sublime Text, but i executed it from the Command Prompt, from IDLE, Double Clicking, and from visual studio, all to the same result. I have no clue what to do about it.

Comment: sorry, that is not multiple pieces of code, just one function when the user clicks the title screen

Comment: You're not updating the screen (`pygame.display.update()`) in your game loop

Comment: worked perfectly! Thank You!

Comment: Cant believe I forgot that

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Can you post your comment as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not updating the screen (`pygame.display.update()`) in your game loop